# How to play current audio time from dragging a vinyl / object up and down

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I have an audio that plays continuously. This audio is represented by a vinyl object where the user can drag the vinyl up or down, but how do i determine the current time of the audio when i drag the vinyl up or down depending on the vinyl objects height and width maybe even the circumference of the round vinyl object.

With SO help i have managed to allow the user to drag the vinyl up and down while the vinyl object is continuously playing.

Below is the UI of the Dj Control Mixer that plays the Vinyl.

[image]

Here is the code, im guessing that the code needs to be added in the touch move event integrate and modify the current time when the vinyl is dragged up or down.

```
            var detectTap = false;
    var detectPlay = false;

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("body").height($(document).height());
        $("#services").height($(document).height());
        $(".container").height($(document).height());
        $(".row").height($(document).height());

        $("#audioplay1").click(function() {

            myAudio=document.getElementById('audio2');
            duration = myAudio.duration;
            myAudio.currentTime = 0;
            myAudio.loop=true;
            myAudio.play();
            detectPlay = true;
            offset = $("#round-play1").offset();
        })

    })

    $(document).on('touchstart click', '#round-play1', function(e){
        var x = e.touches[0].clientX;
        var y = e.touches[0].clientY;
        detectTap = true;
        startDeg = angXY(e);
        myAudio.pause();
        A_x = x;
        A_y = y;

    });

    $(document).on('touchmove click', '#round-play1', function(e){
        var x = e.touches[0].clientX;
        var y = e.touches[0].clientY;
        myAudio.play();
        var deg = angXY(e);

        currentDragTime = (deg - startDeg) / 10;
        if(A_y > y){

            console.log("UP")
            if(deg < 0) //if the vinyl has been rewinded before the start of the audio
            {
                myAudio.currentTime = myAudio.duration + currentDragTime;
            }else{
                myAudio.currentTime = currentDragTime;
            }

        }else{
            console.log("DOWN")
        }

        $("#round-play1").css('-moz-transform', 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)');
        $("#round-play1").css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)');
        $("#round-play1").css('-o-transform', 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)');
        $("#round-play1").css('-ms-transform', 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)');

        A_y = y;

    });

    $(document).on('touchend click', '#round-play1', function(e){
        var x = e.changedTouches[0].pageX;
        var y = e.changedTouches[0].pageY;
        detectTap = false;
        r = getCurrentRotation($("#round-play1")[0]);
    });

    const angXY = (e) => {
        var x = e.touches ? e.touches[0].clientX : e.changedTouches[0].pageX;
        var y = e.touches ? e.touches[0].clientY : e.changedTouches[0].pageY;

        var center_x = (offset.left) + ($("#round-play1").width() / 2);
        var center_y = (offset.top) + ($("#round-play1").height() / 2);
        var mouse_x = x;
        var mouse_y = y;
        var radians = Math.atan2(mouse_x - center_x, mouse_y - center_y);
        var degree = (radians * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 90;

        return degree;
    };

    function getCurrentRotation(el){
        var st = window.getComputedStyle(el, null);
        var tm = st.getPropertyValue("-webkit-transform") ||
                st.getPropertyValue("-moz-transform") ||
                st.getPropertyValue("-ms-transform") ||
                st.getPropertyValue("-o-transform") ||
                st.getPropertyValue("transform") ||
                "none";
        if (tm != "none") {
        var values = tm.split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split(',');
        var angle = Math.round(Math.atan2(values[1],values[0]) * (180/Math.PI));
        return (angle < 0 ? angle + 360 : angle); //adding 360 degrees here when angle < 0 is equivalent to adding (2 * Math.PI) radians before
        }
        return 0;
    }

    r = 0;
    var rpm;
    setInterval(() => {
        if(!detectTap){
            if(detectPlay){
                myAudio.play();
                r = r + 1;
                if(r >= 360){
                    console.log("360");
                    r = 0;
                }


                $("#round-play1")[0].style.transform = `rotate(${r}deg)`;
            }
        }
    }, 10);
```

### UPDATE

Im making little progress on allowing the user to drag the vinyl and play at its current dragged state, this is what i have so far, still trying to get my head round when the vinyl is dragged up or down when do i change the current time:

Need some advice on the code i have changed if this is the right way about it?

Comment: You should consider the RPM rating of the record too! 33, 35, 78 rpm records. Technically, 33.33 rpms for a typical DJ record with a 0.3048m (12") diameter of the vinyl. You can calculate the time of the track based on the radius from the center of the user's touch on vinyl along with its typical speed.

Comment: @StephenTaylor, 12'' diameter, are you saying that the vinyl needs to be a height and width of 12'', but how would this fit on the screen?

Comment: No, no. 12" is the actual diameter of a DJ's vinyl record. You can scale it in your UI. Let's say you scale it 1/10th of the scale, then make the diameter 1.2" on the screen or even just a fixed number of pixels. I only mention the diameter so that you can use the rpm of the record and the on click/touch point of the user's interaction. If the user rotates the vinyl closer to the axis, it'll adjust the time faster than if they move the vinyl near the edge. If a record spins 33 times per minute and the radius is x (scaled), how fast does the time adjust? That's the question you need to answer.

Comment: @StephenTaylor, i have updated the question, am i going the right way about this