# how to get the relative rotation in degrees even after its passed 360 degrees

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

If i have a circle that rotates, and reach's twice round 360 i would get 720 degrees, but when i rotate to 360 or 720 the result would give me 0 degrees but i need the relative degrees so if the circle rotates to 360 the result should be 360 not 0. Is there a formula or functionality to get the exact rotation after its passed 359 degrees.

This is how far i get, but the problem is when the rotation sets back to 0 again which at times the vinyl goes back to the start of the track playing, this is the part im stuck on:

```js
var detectTap = false;
var detectPlay = false;
var lastDeg = 0;
var currentDragTime = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("body").height($(document).height());
  $("#services").height($(document).height());
  $(".container").height($(document).height());
  $(".row").height($(document).height());

  $("#audioplay1").click(function() {

    myAudio = document.getElementById('audio2');
    duration = myAudio.duration;
    myAudio.currentTime = 0;
    myAudio.loop = true;
    myAudio.play();
    detectPlay = true;
    offset = $("#round-play1").offset();
  })

})

$(document).on('touchstart click', '#round-play1', function(e) {
  var x = e.touches ? e.touches[0].clientX : e.changedTouches ? e.changedTouches[0].pageX : null;
  var y = e.touches ? e.touches[0].clientY : e.changedTouches ? e.changedTouches[0].pageY : null;

  if (x && y) {
    detectTap = true;
    startDeg = angXY(e);
    myAudio.pause();
    A_x = x;
    A_y = y;
  } else {
    detectTap = true;
    x = 0
    y = 0;
    myAudio.pause();
  }

});

$(document).on('touchmove click', '#round-play1', function(e) {
  var x = e.touches ? e.touches[0].clientX : e.changedTouches ? e.changedTouches[0].pageX : null;
  var y = e.touches ? e.touches[0].clientY : e.changedTouches ? e.changedTouches[0].pageY : null;

  if (x && y) {
    var deg = angXY(e);

    var t2 = globTime;

    if (A_y > y) {


      if (lastDeg < deg) {
        var t3 = (myAudio.duration / ((myAudio.duration / (deg - startDeg)) * 100));
        currentDragTime = t3 + t2;

        myAudio.currentTime = currentDragTime;
      } else {

        var t3 = (myAudio.duration / ((myAudio.duration / (deg - startDeg)) * 100));
        currentDragTime = t2 + t3;

        myAudio.currentTime = currentDragTime;
      }


    } else {

      if (lastDeg > deg) {

        var t3 = (myAudio.duration / ((myAudio.duration / (startDeg - deg)) * 100));
        currentDragTime = t2 - t3;

        myAudio.currentTime = currentDragTime;

      } else {

        if (Math.round(currentDragTime) == 0) {



        }

        var t3 = (myAudio.duration / ((myAudio.duration / (startDeg - deg)) * 100));
        currentDragTime = t2 - t3;

        myAudio.currentTime = currentDragTime;
      }


    }


    myAudio.play();

    $("#round-play1").css('-moz-transform', 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)');
    $("#round-play1").css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)');
    $("#round-play1").css('-o-transform', 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)');
    $("#round-play1").css('-ms-transform', 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)');

    A_y = y;
    lastDeg = deg;
  }


});

$(document).on('touchend click', '#round-play1', function(e) {
  var x = e.touches ? e.touches[0] ? e.touches[0].clientX : e.changedTouches ? e.changedTouches[0].pageX : null : null;
  var y = e.touches ? e.touches[0] ? e.touches[0].clientY : e.changedTouches ? e.changedTouches[0].pageY : null : null;


  detectTap = false;
  myAudio.play();
  lockUp = false;
  lockDown = false;
  //r = getCurrentRotation($("#round-play1")[0]);
});

const angXY = (e) => {
  var x = e.touches ? e.touches[0].clientX : e.changedTouches[0].pageX;
  var y = e.touches ? e.touches[0].clientY : e.changedTouches[0].pageY;

  var center_x = (offset.left) + ($("#round-play1").width() / 2);
  var center_y = (offset.top) + ($("#round-play1").height() / 2);
  var mouse_x = x;
  var mouse_y = y;
  var radians = Math.atan2(mouse_x - center_x, mouse_y - center_y);
  var degree = (radians * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 180;

  return degree;
};

const angXY2 = (e) => {
  var x = e.touches ? e.touches[0].clientX : e.changedTouches[0].pageX;
  var y = e.touches ? e.touches[0].clientY : e.changedTouches[0].pageY;

  var center_x = (offset.left) + ($("#round-play1").width() / 2);
  var center_y = (offset.top) + ($("#round-play1").height() / 2);
  var mouse_x = x;
  var mouse_y = y;
  var radians = Math.atan2(mouse_x - center_x, mouse_y - center_y);
  var degree = (radians * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 180;

  return degree;
};


function getCurrentRotation(el) {
  var st = window.getComputedStyle(el, null);
  var tm = st.getPropertyValue("-webkit-transform") ||
    st.getPropertyValue("-moz-transform") ||
    st.getPropertyValue("-ms-transform") ||
    st.getPropertyValue("-o-transform") ||
    st.getPropertyValue("transform") ||
    "none";
  if (tm != "none") {
    var values = tm.split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split(',');
    var angle = Math.round(Math.atan2(values[1], values[0]) * (180 / Math.PI));
    return (angle < 0 ? angle + 360 : angle); //adding 360 degrees here when angle < 0 is equivalent to adding (2 * Math.PI) radians before
  }
  return 0;
}
r = 0;
var globTime = 0;
setInterval(() => {
  if (!detectTap) {
    if (detectPlay) {
      r = r + 1;

      if (r > 360) {
        r = 0;
      }

      globTime = myAudio.currentTime;

      $("#round-play1")[0].style.transform = `rotate(${r}deg)`;
    }
  }
}, 10);
```

```css
#services .block .icon-block {
  border: 4px solid #f9398a;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: left;
  background-color: #181818;
  padding: 10px;
}

#services .block .icon-block2 {
  border: 4px solid #1bc5fd;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: left;
  background-color: #181818;
  padding: 10px;
}

#services .block .icon-block a {
  font-size: 25px;
}

#services .block .upper-block::before {
  border: 2px solid red;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -99;
}

#services .block .upper-block {
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.round-play {
  width: 225px;
  height: 225px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: -1.5px;
  animation-duration: 100s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

.record {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #000;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 225px;
  height: 225px;
  background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 1%, rgba(206, 70, 38, 1) 2%, rgba(206, 70, 38, 1) 21%, rgba(206, 70, 38, 1) 22%, rgba(206, 70, 38, 1) 23%, rgba(206, 70, 38, .5) 24%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 25%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 40%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .1) 41%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 43%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .1) 45%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 46%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 53%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .1) 54%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 55%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 60%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .1) 61%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 62%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .1) 63%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 64%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .1) 65%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 66%), -webkit-linear-gradient( 45deg, #000 0%, #000 30%, rgba(47, 47, 47, 1) 50%, #000 70%, #000 100%);
  background-image: radial-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 1%, rgba(206, 70, 38, 1) 2%, rgba(206, 70, 38, 1) 21%, rgba(206, 70, 38, 1) 22%, rgba(206, 70, 38, 1) 23%, rgba(206, 70, 38, .5) 24%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 25%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 40%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .1) 41%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 43%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .1) 45%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 46%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 53%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .1) 54%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 55%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 60%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .1) 61%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 62%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .1) 63%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 64%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .1) 65%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 66%), linear-gradient( 45deg, #000 0%, #000 30%, rgba(47, 47, 47, 1) 50%, #000 70%, #000 100%);
}

.divbar1 {
  width: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #f9398a;
  position: relative;
}

.divcircle {
  z-index: 100;
  border-radius: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 46%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: white;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

.divbar2 {
  width: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #1bc5fd;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="services">
  <div class="container block" style="width: 100%;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6 upper-block">
        <div class="icon-block">
          <div id="round-play1" class="round-play record"></div>
          <audio id="audio2" src="https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3">
                                </audio>
        </div>

        <div style="width:10px;" class="">

          <div class="divbar1"></div>
          <div class="divcircle"></div>
          <div class="divbar2"></div>

        </div>

        <div class="icon-block2" style="">
          <div id="round-play1" class="round-play record"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button id="audioplay1">Audio</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: `angle ? angle % 360 || 360 : 0` ?

Comment: If you consider the relative position at a single point in time (when you query it), then there's no way to know it's "already gone round twice" - when you look at a clock and it's "8:00" - there's no way to know that's Tuesday or Friday or December (etc).

Comment: @76484, tried your code or solution but no luck.

Comment: ok if i had a current time of lets say 00:01:24 seconds could i determine the angle in degrees using the current time?:

Comment: You are setting it so shouldn't you already know what the value is?

Comment: @epascarello, yes setting it is fine but still when i use the code above, this does not give me the relative degrees, the value comes back as 90 degrees even when i specify 810 degrees, i understand what you are saying, but this is just to show how do i get the value after it is set in another function at a later time

Comment: But you have the value 810.... why do you need to read the value when you have 810 already....

Comment: this question relates to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75733579/how-to-play-current-audio-time-from-dragging-a-vinyl-object-up-and-down

Comment: That question is not at a single point in time.  As the user rotates, the amount to rotate is determined (I assume) by the mouse position - and thus, the position in the music track is determine - by the mouse position, *not* the rotation position.   If not the current mouse position, then the *culmination* of previous mouse moves/positions - ie not at a single point of time.   So whatever controls the position should also be used to control the answer to *this* question - ie don't read from the HTML, read from the variable that is used to set the position (as per comments above).

Comment: Can you show us how you decide on the rotations?

Comment: @AHaworth, i have posted the full code, should be in the setinterval and touch move event where the rotations decide where to play the track, the set interval just simplay keeps track of the global time to know when the track stopped when dragging

Comment: If you have an HTML+CSS+JS question, please show the problem you're having using a runnable snippet. Also, since you're asking about CSS animations, [put that in your post](/help/how-to-ask). You're not asking about how to "get" a value, you are setting an angle greater than 360 and expecting the CSS animation to rotate by that many degrees instead of by the remainder of mod 360.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, i have added the code snippet

Comment: Please just rewrite the whole post: none of this comment thread was necessary if you just wrote it as "I need a CSS animation to rotate more than once if I set an angle greater than 360" with the [mcve] snippet (and only the snippet, not any of the non-snippet blocks. Those are not necessary if the snippet shows off the problem). Right now that snippet contains _way_ too much code. Only show enough code to show off the problem you're asking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set an angle greater than 360, and it'll quite happily rotate that many degrees. Just keep track of the values you're using so that you're *actually* setting the right angle, for the right CSS property.

The following snippet will keep rotating a div between 0 and 900 degrees each time you click "go", and at no point will that angle get applied "modulo 360":

```js
go.addEventListener(`click`, () => {
  const { style } = box;
  const deg = parseFloat(style.getPropertyValue(`--deg`) || 0);
  const update = (Math.random() * 900)|0;
  style.setProperty(`--update`, update);
  style.setProperty(`--deg`, deg + update);
  degrees.textContent = `added ${update} degrees`;
});
```

```css
div {
  --deg: 0;
  --update: 0;
  --speed: calc(var(--update) / 360 * 5s);
  background: red;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  transform: rotate(calc(var(--deg) * 1deg));
  transition: transform var(--speed) linear;
  margin-bottom: 0.4em;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
<button id="go">go</button>
<span id="degrees"></span>
```

Comment: i have written the question again like you asked here, shall i delete that post i just created:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75773144/how-to-get-the-relative-angle-or-degrees-even-if-its-past-360

Comment: Just update _this post_, don't post a new question. There will be some comments that will no longer apply, and that's good: all of those are implicit requests for you to update your post to include all the details in a concise manner.